# Foreign Keys and Primary Keys at the same time

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

I am trying to create table (orderdetails2); the table has two FKs and a PKs on the two FK columns.  Here is my code:

#### Version 1

```
    create table OrderDetails2 (
PFOrder_ID Number(3)  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orderr(Order_ID),
PFProduct_ID Number(3) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(Product_ID),
CONSTRAINT PF PRIMARY KEY (PFOrder_ID,PFProduct_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (PFProudct_ID)
REFERENCES Product(Product_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (PFOrder_ID)
REFERENCES Orderr(Order_ID),
```

#### Version 2

```
            create table OrderDetails2 (
    PFOrder_ID Number(3)
    PFProduct_ID Number(3) 
    CONSTRAINT PF PRIMARY KEY (PFOrder_ID,PFProduct_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (PFProudct_ID) REFERENCES Product(Product_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (PFOrder_ID) REFERENCES Orderr(Order_ID)
);
```

I am using Oracle express.  A problem pops when I run the code.  Here it is (for version 1):

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You have a trailing comma at the end of the last line and a "missing right parenthesis" at the end, to close the parens started in line one in the "create table" statement.

Comment: i updated the code , please take a look again

Comment: Please update the popped up problem too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from the variant of the code with:

```
create table OrderDetails2 (
    PFOrder_ID Number(3)
    PFProduct_ID Number(3) 
    CONSTRAINT PF PRIMARY KEY (PFOrder_ID,PFProduct_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (PFProudct_ID) REFERENCES Product(Product_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (PFOrder_ID) REFERENCES Orderr(Order_ID)
);
```

You are missing a comma after `PFOrder_ID NUMBER(3)` and after `PFPoduct_ID NUMBER(3)`.

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails2
(
    PFOrder_ID   NUMBER(3),
    PFProduct_ID NUMBER(3), 
    CONSTRAINT PF   PRIMARY KEY (PFOrder_ID, PFProduct_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (PFProduct_ID) REFERENCES Product(Product_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (PFOrder_ID)   REFERENCES Orderr(Order_ID)
);
```

The PRIMARY KEY clause has to be separate from the PFProduct_ID column because it is a compound key.  (Is `Orderr` spelled correctly?)  And `PFProudct_ID` in the original is incorrect.  If you're a programmer, you have to be able to spell consistently (even if not correctly in the broader sense of writing).

Comment: Also, as a general comment (which I might lift into the answer), the names 'PK', 'FK_1' and 'FK_2' are rather too generic; you'd probably be better off with 'PF_OrderDetails2' and 'FK_1_OrderDetails2' and 'FK_2_OrderDetails2'.

Comment: another case of where consistency is more useful than correctness. cope up with a naming convention for constraints, indices, triggers etc and stick to it.

Answer (score 2):

Change the last comma to a close parenthesis: `)`.

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails2
(
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (PFOrder_ID) REFERENCES Orderr(Order_ID)
)
```

Comment: i updated the code in the question , please take a look again